# Measured quantities as probability distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, error-propagation

Measured quantities are most frequently treated as real numbers or as confidence intervals bounded by real numbers. There's a suggestion there that measurements are actually probability distributions with the reported value being its global maximum. Are there/can there be any formalisms that treat measurements as probability distributions?